# In bootstrap 3.0 how to add a grid cell or dynamically adjust margin of first cell in alternate rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create a brick pattern where in every other row the first brick is half. This can be achieved by using half column width in grid when you know how many cells go in one row.

However, on smaller screens / on resize when the cells collapse to create new dynamic rows, the brick pattern breaks.

Example of brick pattern: http://plato.acadiau.ca/courses/educ/reid/geometry/brick/Mvc-006s.jpg

The below code will work when there are 5 cells in a row. If the screen is resized to have only 3 cells in a row, then the third row will not begin with half brick as intended and pattern will break.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 halfbrick"></div>                
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
        </div>    

        <div class="row">                
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
        </div>    

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 halfbrick "></div>                
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 brick"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best i could do for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/SY7Wr/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 brick"></div>                
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
    </div>    
     <div class="row">                
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 brick"></div>
    </div>   

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 brick"></div>                
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 brick"></div>
    </div>
```

The fatal flaw of this is that its not always 100% the with of the containing row:

- Large: 11/12 % of the width
- Mid: 10/12 % of the width
- sm: 10/12 % of the width
- xs: 12/12 % of the width

that means the for large, mid, sm there is white space on the right side...
Using the bootstrap grid, I think this is the best you can do. Otherwise you might want to consider using a custom grid system to make it work or some javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with, I used the responsive utility classes to adjust the number of bricks in order to keep everything even at all breakpoints:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 brick"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 brick"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-3 brick"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-3 brick"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-1 brick"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-3 brick hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 brick hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-3 brick hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 brick hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
</div>
```

Each of these `.row` elements will give you 2 rows of bricks in your page.

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/SY7Wr/7/show/)**

Comment: Thank you for coming up with the solution. This absolutely works. I chose the earlier answer because it satisfies an underlying business requirement. The bricks will contain some data, and cannot have some panels hidden when screen is resized. Using the utility classes to auto hide was a cool approach to solve the basic pattern problem..